# Installed many Python on macOS

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use Selenium. It can run on VS Code but closes immediately.

After that I've tried to run .py on terminal but it displays this:

```
MacBook-Air Selenium % python3 FillTest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ben/Documents/Coding/Selenium/FillTest.py", line 1, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
```

It shows that line even though I've installed Selenium. Then I go to check the directory. It displays like this:

```
MacBook-Air ~ % printenv PATH
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin:
/usr/local/bin:
/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:
/usr/bin:
/bin:
/usr/sbin:
/sbin:
/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin
```

On VSC it displays this:

```
MacBook-Air Selenium % where python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3
```

How can I remove this mess?

Comment: WHAT shows that you have installed Selenium?  HOW did you install Selenium?  Remember that your VSCode may have its own installation of Python, separate from the system version and a homebrew version.  You have to install the package where you need to use it.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: If you do `ls -l /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python3`, what does it show?  Those are symbolic links to other places.  If they all point to `/Library/Frameworks`, then they're all the same.  You just have to choose which one YOU are going to use, and set up all of your tools to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Here are solutions to both parts of your question: selecting a Python version to use in VSCode, and managing Python installations on your device.

1. If you only want to be able to access Python package normally in VSCode, you can use shortcuts **Ctrl+Shift+P** and type **Python: Select Interpreter** to choose the interpreter where you installed the package.
2. If you want to delete some version of Python in your mac, you can type `sudo rm -rf /path/to/python` and press **Enter** to delete the Python version at the specified path. Replace `/path/to/python` with the actual path to the Python version you want to delete. *If you know how that particular version was installed (e.g. Homebrew, Nix, etc.), it is best to uninstall it using the software that was used to install it.*

Comment: If someone is behaving responsibly, they will have installed Python with a package manager (Homebrew, Nix, MacPorts, etc), and they should uninstall it the same way. Unless someone went out of their way to do a manual build, using `rm -rf` to uninstall software leaves recordkeeping out-of-date and is generally bad form.